# Can't get the footer to align right vs left

Tags: html, css

I've been following the steps here & in other sites, but I've been unable to achieve it. The idea is to have the texts aligned to both the bottom left & the bottom right.

This is my HTML code:

```
  <footer class="footer">
      <div>
        <p class = "alignleft"> Copyright &copy; Ask Alansky 2019 </p>
        <p class = "alignright"> Empowered by gA </p>
        <div style= "clear: both"> </div>
        <!-- <div style = "clearboth"> </div> -->
      </div>
  </footer>
```

This is my CSS code:

```
  .footer{
  padding: 25px 0;
  text-align: center;
  }

  .alignleft{
  float: left;
  }

  .alignright{
  float: right;
  }
```

I'm new to this, so I tried to use the following, but it didn't work:

```
  .clearboth{
  clear: both;
  }
```

I want to have it in the same line, but aligned to the left & right. I'm getting it in different lines, & centered... ¬¬

Please advise; I'm stuck.

Comment: Here's your code in a fiddle...seems to work (https://jsfiddle.net/j3z1Lfda/).  Is this not what you're getting?  Also, what is your screen width?  They will push below each other if the screen is not wide enough.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to get, but in my page it shows two consecutive lines. My screen wide is about 60cm.

Comment: If you limit the width on both to 50% they will avoid pushing one down to the next line: https://jsfiddle.net/j3z1Lfda/1/

Comment: Auto margins work great for this. Try changing `.alignLeft{ margin-right:auto; }` and `.alignRight{ margin-left:auto; }`. Setting a margin to auto makes it take up all the available space it can in that direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Float can become sloppy, make your life easier with a little flex.

```css
.footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
    <span>Copyright &copy; Ask Alansky 2019</span>
    <span>Empowered by gA</span>
</footer>
```